# Is it possible to print a photo so it can be mounted on a globe?

Tags: software, printing, image-processing

I'd like to transform an image so that it can be mounted on a sphere. I'd like to use an image of a map (see the One Piece world map on the image), but it could be anything. Here is a kind of [Family Picnic Photo](http://www.monicaros.org/wp-content/upload/picnic01.JPG) that I could use, (this isn't my family, is just a Google result). I'd like to do this as a gift for my cousin on his birthday. I'm beginner on photo processing and manipulation and normally I use Linux, but every suggestion is welcome.

[image: One Piece World Map]

I would like a way to transform this image or photo into a "globular" image/photo, to put on something like this:

[image: Real World Map]

Is there any software that can do this for me? If not, how would I go about computing the necessary slices of my image to fit?

Comment: Can you give a practical example of how this might  _really_ be useful for something other than a map?

Comment: @mattdm I'm thinking print a photo, if all family in a panoramic version and put it on a globe. I'm not sure if will works well but I'd like to try.

Comment: Okay. :) Put that in the question, and I think we have no doubt as to its on-topicness.

Comment: [This answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/what-projections-should-i-use-to-make-my-own-globe) on GIS SE might be of interest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[IP-Slicer](http://www.bruno.postle.net/2001/ip-slicer/) perl script can create slices which can stuck together into a ball. You can define the number of slices.

The following command will create 12 slices, where the sphere circumference is 1500 pixels.

```
sphere-slicer.pl 12 1500 sampleimage.jpg
```

Sample input:

[image: input for IP-Slicer]

Output (12 images):

[image: output1]
[image: output2]
[image: output3] 
[image: output4]
[image: output5]
[image: output6]
[image: output7]
[image: output8]
[image: output9]
[image: output10]
[image: output11]
[image: output12]

Comment: Slick tool and, if he's on Linux, should be easy to get it going.

Comment: @asalamon74 Very interesting. I think this solve my entire question. Really thanks.

Comment: If I have a globe with x cm of perimeter, what the number of pixels of this globe?

Comment: That depends on the printing. Check this question about dpi: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/what-does-dpi-mean

Comment: I have a little difficult to make this script works. But it runs ok  to me now. Thx @asalamon74 . But it's unclear to me wich "sphere circumpherence" parameter pass to the script to print the image and  fit it exactly on the globe.

I had find this [site](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/typography/calculator/pixel-(X)-to-centimeter-[cm]/) and I got `1500 pixel (X) = 39.6875 centimeter`, so your outputs it's for a globe with `39.7 cm` of circumpherece?

Am I need the dpi resolution of a image before run the script?

Can you explain a bit more how to do this? =)

Comment: If you print at 300dpi then 1500pixels=1500/300=5 inches. If you print 100dpi, it's 1500/100=15 inches. Check your printing software, probably you can set the dpi (or at least it will print it to you).

Comment: from top to bottom of each of 12 images is the half of the diamater of your circle!

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting page offering both online and offline tools to create "gores" to be glued on a real sphere.

The most interesting is "USGS Daisy-Petal creator (requires .NET 2.0)", which creates "half gores" joined at the poles, thus making much easier to align and glue.

http://www.winski.net/?page_id=7

Answer (score -2):

GIMP has an extension called MathMap that can do this, too.

Comment: welcome to photo.stackexchange. A longer answer would be better, tells us how you use MathMap for example.

Comment: I agree that a longer answer would be better. For example, what are MathMaps's capabilities and limitations?